# How to hide poster flashing when switching between two videos in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have a video with two versions, SD and HD, which is used to compare different qualities of a certain video file.

Here is the snippet:

```
<div className={`video__switch ${isObscured ? "" : "is-obscured"}`}>
    <button className={`video__switch__value u-type--sans u-type--delta u-slant ${isHD ? "" : "active"}`} onClick={this.handleIsSD.bind(this)}>
                      <span className="u-unslant u-type--bold">SD</span>
                    </button>
    <button className={`video__switch__value u-type--sans u-type--delta u-slant ${isHD ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={this.handleIsHD.bind(this)}>
                      <span className="u-unslant u-type--bold">HD</span>
                    </button>
</div>

<div className={`video__media ${isObscured ? "" : "is-obscured"}`}>
    <video loop ref="vidRef" poster="images/poster.jpg" className="header__video js-headerVideo" src={videoUrl} />
</div>
```

`handleIsSD` and `handleIsHD` just calls functions that set the other video to play, it's not important for this question.

`isObscured` is used as an overlay before first play of the video, and is invisible later on.

`video__switch__value` button is used for changing between SD and HD quality.

The problem is that I have also poster image on the videos which is a first frame from a video, and it always flashes for a few ms on each HD/SD switch in the video. And the first frame poster in the middle of a video looks really odd. Is there some way to fix this?

I've tried removing the poster, but then I only get black screen flashes.

Main idea is to grab the screen from the exact moment of switching quality and placing it as a poster until the other quality video loads, but I'm not sure that is doable. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that can be easily achieved using combination of technique.

When the user changes between SD and HD, then capture a image of the current frame using techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883037/generate-a-thumbnail-snapshot-of-a-video-file-selected-by-a-file-input-at-a-spec). Then from the `canvas`, get the image as `dataURI`, set it as a poster of the video element and switch the source and then do your stuff.